# Contact Form 7 allow duplicate after 24 hours

Tags: database, wordpress, validation, duplicates, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 for to capture leads on our site.
I am also using the CFDB plugin to add a validation rule to prevent all duplicates on the site using.

```
function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
    $exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
    $atts = array();
    $atts['show'] = $fieldName;
    $atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
    $atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
    $exp->export($formName, $atts);
    $found = false;
    while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
        $found = true;
    }
    return $found;
}
function my_validate_email($result, $tag) {
    $formName = 'email_form'; // Change to name of the form containing this field
    $fieldName = 'email_123'; // Change to your form's unique field name
    $errorMessage = 'Email has already been submitted'; // Change to your error message
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if ($name == $fieldName) {
        if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

We are now required to allow a duplicate entry if a user retries after a 24 hour period.

Our Proposal is to run a cron job to flag entries that are older than 24 hours and then allow a user to proceed. We have included a new table column (allow_duplicate) to flag the entry.

Any advice on how to structure the validation on functions.php would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the only field that you're checking on the email?

Comment: yes I am, but the architecture is flexible enough that I can change this. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Just thinking of another way to do this. Using transients instead of CFDB

Comment: I am unfamilar with transients. Any advice however at this point would be very valuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So me personally... I would use the [Transient API](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/). With Transients, you can set the expiration to 24 hours, and remove the need for a cron task.  First... Set the transient using the hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail` then check for the existence of the transient with your validate filter.  The transient will expire 24 hours after initial submission.

Set your contact form ID in the function `dd_handle_form_submission`

```php
// capture data after contact form submit
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dd_handle_form_submission' ); 
function dd_handle_form_submission( $contact_form ) {
    // Check Form ID
    if( 2744 !== $contact_form->id() ) return; // Use your form ID here
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        // Set the Transient
        $transient_name = 'cf7_has_submitted_' . $posted_data['email_123'];
        set_transient($transient_name, true, 1 * DAY_IN_SECONDS);
    }
    return;
}

// Custom Validation Filter
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'my_validate_email', 20, 2);
function my_validate_email($result, $tag) {
    $fieldName = 'email_123'; // Change to your form's unique field name
    $errorMessage = 'Email has already been submitted'; // Change to your error message
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if ($name == $fieldName) {
        // Create the Transient Name to lookup with the email field
        $transient = 'cf7_has_submitted_' . $_POST[$name];
        // Lookup transient
        if (false !== get_transient($transient)) $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted the issue.